# Error with objective-c macro

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macros

Im new to writing macros in Xcode and am having a problem writing my own NSLog replacement. I've been using a few examples but want to tweak them slightly, so they act more like Log4.

Im trying to write a 2nd macro (or ideally just a delegate of the first) which takes a log level variable as well as the string and arguments for formatting. But everytime I try and pass a varible (in this case l) I get a SIGART error NSArgumentException. The first macro works fine

```
#define MLog(s,...) \
[MLog logFile:__FILE__ lineNumber:__LINE__ \
format:(s),##__VA_ARGS__]

#define MLogWithLevel(l,s,...) \
[MLog logFile2:__FILE__ lineNumber:__LINE__ logLevel:l \
format:(s),##__VA_ARGS__]
```

This is my method definition

```
+(void)logFile:(char*)sourceFile 
        lineNumber:(int)lineNumber
        format:(NSString*)format, ...;

+(void)logFile2:(char*)sourceFile       
lineNumber:(int)lineNumber
        logLevel:(int)logLevel
        format:(NSString*)format, ...;
```

The exceptions:

> +[MLog logFile2:lineNumber:logLevel::format:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to class
>   0x51600 2010-07-10 10:49:21.408
>   Celebspotter[34433:207] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '+[MLog
>   logFile2:lineNumber:logLevel::format:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to class
>   0x51600'

My test log message:

```
MLogWithLevel(0: @"log at level %i", 0);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the colon, use a comma:

```
MLogWithLevel(0, @"log at level %i", 0);
// fix here:   ^
```

Comment: @tiegermain -- don't forget to checkmark this answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: I would have but it was too soon after posting!